# C programming, how would I find the oldest date in an array of date structures?

Tags: c, arrays, date, loops, structure

I have a nested structure, the "inside structure" is a date structure with the members; day, month and year. The structures are contained in a dynamic array. I would like to loop through the structures and find which struct has the oldest date. I'm new to programming and not quite sure on how to approach this. Please help. Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//define structure to store students birth date
struct date
{
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
};
//define structure to store student info and date structure for birth date
struct studentInfo
{
    int iD;
    struct date birthDate;
    int phone;
};

int main(void)
{
    //declare and initialize variables
    int recNum = 0;     //number of records
    struct studentInfo * records = NULL;    //struct pointer, array
    //request user input  and store in recNum for record amount
    printf("\nHow many students do you need to enter records for?:");
    scanf ("%d",&recNum);
    //dynamically allocate memory
    records = (struct studentInfo*)malloc((sizeof(struct studentInfo)*recNum));
    //loop through records and request/store values from user
    int count;
    int studentNum=1;
    for(count=0;count<recNum;count++)
    {
        printf("Please enter the following for student number %d\n",studentNum);
        //request and store student ID
        printf("Student ID#:");
        scanf ("%d",&records[count].iD);
        //request and store student phone number
        printf("Student phone# (numbers only, 10 digits):");
        scanf ("%d",&records[count].phone);

        //error checking, check if phone number is 10 digits
        int phoneCount = 0;
        int phoneCopy = records[count].phone;
        while(phoneCopy != 0)
        {
            phoneCopy /= 10;
            phoneCount++;
        }
        if (phoneCount != 10)
        {
            printf("The number you have entered is not 10 digits, please re-enter:");
            scanf ("%d",&records[count].phone);
        }

        //request and store student birthdate
        printf("Student birthday (mm/dd/yyyy):");
        scanf("%d/%d/%d",&records[count].birthDate.month,&records[count].birthDate.day,
                &records[count].birthDate.year);

        //test stuff
        printf("Student number %d has an ID of %d and a phone number of %d\n", studentNum,
                records[count].iD, records[count].phone);
        studentNum++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: do you have array of struct? show you code

Comment: Try posting some code first.

Comment: Iterate over the array, and maintain a reference to the oldest (presumably, the smallest, if we're talking about something like epoch times) date encountered so far. Just like a basic `Math.min()` implementation.

Comment: Use a sorted array, add new dates into correct positions so any iteration/loop would be fast.

Comment: Keep a copy of the current oldest value (initially, the first value in the array); step through the rest of the array, comparing the new values with the oldest, taking a copy of the newly found oldest when necessary.

Comment: Any solution is probably going to involve having a comparison function, finding the oldest by just looping through would need to know what "old" is. Could also sort the list, but just the same, that requires a comparison function. Something like `int date_compare(struct date * d1, struct date * d2)`

Answer (score 0):

```
#define NUMCMP(x,y) (((x) < (y)) ? -1 : ((x) > (y)) ? 1 : 0)

int compar_student_byDate(const struct studentInfo *student1, const struct studentInfo *student2){
    struct date date1 = student1->birthDate;
    struct date date2 = student2->birthDate;
    int tmp;
    if((tmp=NUMCMP(date1.year, date2.year))==0){
        if((tmp=NUMCMP(date1.month, date2.month))==0)
            return NUMCMP(date1.day, date2.day);
        else
            return tmp;
    } else
        return tmp;
}

struct studentInfo *oldest(struct studentInfo *records, int recNum){
    struct studentInfo *old = records;
    int i;
    for(i = 1;i<recNum;++i){
        if(compar_student_byDate(old, &records[i])>0)
            old = &records[i];
    }
    return old;
}
```

at main

```
struct studentInfo *old_student = oldest(records, recNum);
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, first I should tell you that this is a question that can have many many many correct answeres.
You could instead of creating an array of strucutures `studentInfo`, create a tree and whenever you insert a new node into the tree keep the root node as the oldest among many other solutions. Anyway for your simple case, a simple solution could be as follows

Step 0. You want to find

```
studentInfo *oldest = records;
```

Step 1. Iterate through the array

```
studentInfo *traveler;
for(traveler = records; i<recNum; i++, traveler++)
```

Step 2. Compare the date from oldest and traveler.

```
if(oldest->birthDate.year > traveler->birthDate.year && 
   oldest->birthDate.month > traveler->birthDate.month &&
   oldest->birthDate.day > traveler->birthDate.day)
```

Step 3. Update the oldest record that you have found every time you find one

```
oldest = traveler;
```

When you finish the iteration, the oldest record should be the one you are looking for.